# Item selected from a spinner displayed in a button

Tags: android, button, spinner

I'd like to display a certain value in a button upon selected something from my spinner. But it's not doing its thing. Please have a look on my codings:

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    int index = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();

    if(index == 0){
        strCalories = "188 calories";
        calories.setText(strCalories);
    }
    else if ( index == 1 ){
        strCalories = "185 calories";
        calories.setText(strCalories);
    }
    else if ( index == 2 ){
        strCalories = "126 calories";
        calories.setText(strCalories);
    }
    else if ( index == 3 ){
        strCalories = "149 calories";
        calories.setText(strCalories);
    }
    else if ( index == 4 ){
        strCalories = "81 calories";
        calories.setText(strCalories);
    }
    else if ( index == 5 ){
        strCalories = "66 calories";
        calories.setText(strCalories);
    }
    else if ( index == 6 ){
        strCalories = "46 calories";
        calories.setText(strCalories);
    }
    else if ( index == 7 ){
        strCalories = "89 calories";
        calories.setText(strCalories);
    }

}

        public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch( v.getId() ){
    case R.id.btBreadWhiteSave:
        String mealname = selected;

        String servng = calories.getText().toString();

        if ( ( mealname.isEmpty() || servng.isEmpty() ) ){

            // call for custom toast
            viewErrorToast();
        }

        else {

        boolean didItWork = true;

        try{

            BreakFastLog entry = new BreakFastLog(Bread_White.this);
            entry.open();

            entry.createEntry(mealname, servng);

            entry.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                didItWork = false;
                viewErrorToast();
            }finally{
                if (didItWork){
                    viewBMRSavedToast();
                }

            }
        } // end of if else statement
        break;
```

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/ihealthfirst" >

<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/tabs_menu" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvWhiteBread"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/whitebread"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spWhiteBread"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/white_bread_prompt"
    android:entries="@array/white_bread_arrays" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btBreadWhiteCalories"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btBreadWhiteSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing in here? Please help me find what went wrong here. thanks.

Comment: you can just use `int position` provided in the parameter for `index`

Comment: You could optimize your code, but it looks fine... Perhaps something is awry in your layout? Please post this XML and how you define `calories`.

Comment: @Sam my list of spinner values comes from string-arrays.

Comment: i've included my layout ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position` passed in as the argument for the onItemSelected callback as the index. Not `getSelectedItemPosition()`

Comment: hi i use string array here to load my data

Comment: The position would then be equal to the index of the element in the string array too. Assuming the string array is loaded in the spinner in the correct order.

Comment: `position` returned by `onItemSelected` is the position of the object in the spinner. Can you give more details as to the exact error you are getting?

Comment: i'm not getting an error but it's just not displaying the calories whenever i choose from my spinner